# Unable to reach angles values of a trigonometric equation.

Tags: trigonometry

For,
$$2\sin x\cos x + \sin x = 0\\
2\sin x\cos x = -\sin x\\
2\cos x = -1\\
\cos x = -1/2\\
x = \arccos (-1/2)$$
$x = \{-120^\circ, 120^\circ\}$ for a range of $-180^\circ \le x\le180^\circ$

The range of values according to my textbook include $\{-180, -120, 0, 120, 180\}$

I am unable to reach the values $\{-180, 0, 180.\}$

Comment: The classical fallacy of [dividing by zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy#Division_by_zero).

Answer (score 1):

Those values are when sin x =0.

Comment: I do not seem to understand , the sinx has been eliminated why would it be taken into consideration.

Comment: @user361318 You cannot easily divide by $0$ on both sides. Remember that $\sin(0)=\sin(-180^\circ)=\sin(180^\circ)=0$. If you eliminate $\sin x$ you're assuming (and studying) the cases where $\sin x\ne0$, but omitted the three cases where $\sin(x)=0$.

Comment: I am still oblivious how sinx can be still valid after both sides are divided by sinx.

Comment: Before you divide by sin x, you have the possibility of sin x =0 being a solution. This gives the possibilities 0, 180, -180. After dividing by sin x, these are no longer a possibility, and the other answers are all that is left.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$
\sin x(2\cos x+1)=0 \iff \left\{\sin x=0 \quad \mbox{or} \quad (2\cos x+1)=0\right\}
$

Comment: I like the answer (+1), but at this level. the symbol "$\lor$" may not be understood by OP to mean $\,\text{or}$. It's just a matter of preference, but I prefer to use \text to spell out "or" and "and" in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks mate I got this now!

Comment: @amWhy. Y agree, but it's habit ....Fixed!

Comment: @EmilioNovati  I know very well what you mean! ;-)